# What is .tfc file and how can I use it

Tags: delphi, uiimageview, file-format, paradox

I got a database from my client which is .db file to develop new software. At this software I need to open images. After couple research I could open it by paradox dbase reader and I found my images files to open with software. They were stored name of .tfc file in database.

My question is what is this .tfc file and how can I open(or convert different format) them from my application.

Extra information:

1. My Application will be Visual Studio Winform app.
2. We know, old program which is developed to use this database, is developed by
   Delphi

Possibilities about file

1. Tfc file format can be converted file format from paradox to save images to database
2. I found some information about tfc that is this file format is a "catalog" file

Comment: or it could be that it is a custom format with that extension, do you have the source code of the Delphi application or can you contact the team/developer?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot contact with them and I do not have source code of old application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) could give you some additional information about that file's format.

Comment: Then it should be some custom format. In that case the best source of information about it - source code of your old Delphi application.

Comment: Also you could open your files in hex editor, and try to analyse them by comparing with each other. But this involves some experience.

Comment: No, sorry. Try googling "file reverse engineering".

Comment: I got some information about file, the someone who used same database as me, developed one web application with that database and they could convert this .tfc files to .tiff format. Could it be any clue for reason?